# Using jQuery Mobile call a Popup using custom button image

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to call a JQM Popup using a custom image as a button.  Using the following, I can call an external site, but I can't seem to get it to call a JQM popup.

```
    <a href="http://example.com"><img src="../MapPin1.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need `data-rel="popup"` in your anchor tag for JQM popups, and the `href` is supposed to contain the ID of the popup element (not a hyperlink).

Here's an example:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup"><img src="../MapPin1.png" /></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

See: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/

Comment: Scratch that...  working just fine now.  Thanks for push.  :-)

Comment: You can use virtually anything in an anchor tag. What does the code of your entire page look like?

Comment: Make sure your JQM is referenced in your HTML. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnuph/